# How can I use a type as the keys in an object type?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a very simple interface:

```
interface FXRatesBySymbol {
  [key: string]: number;
}
```

However I'd like to be more specific about allowable keys.

I have a type called CurrencyPair created using [template literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

```
type CurrencyPair = "GBPGBP" | "GBPUSD" | "USDGBP" | "USDUSD"
```

I wish to use CurrencyPair as the type for the key in this object.

```
interface FXRatesBySymbol {
  [key: CurrencyPair]: number;
}
```

This fails with:

```
(parameter) key: "GBPGBP" | "GBPUSD" | "USDGBP" | "USDUSD"
An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.
```

I have looked for the [object documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) to find out what a mapped object type is but haven't been able to find mention of a mapped object type is.

I have also looked at the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) documentation and tried:

```
interface FXRatesBySymbol {
  [Property in keyof CurrencyPair]: number;
}
```

But this is a syntax error.

**How can I use an type as the keys in an object type?**

Comment: That’s not an enum, it’s a union of string literals (and they are string literals, not template literals). A mapped type is a type of the form `{[K in X]: Y}` and you really just want `type FXRatesBySymbol = {[K in CurrencyPair]: number}` or `type FXRatesBySymbol = Record<CurrencyPair, number>`or `interface FXRatesBySymbol extends Record <CurrencyPair, number> {}`.

Comment: I’d love to write up an answer (or more likely find a duplicate) but I’m on mobile.  Someone with a real computer might get here first 

Comment: @jcalz You're right I've fixed the question to say 'type' instead of enum.

Comment: @jcalz and yes your answer works (I found the same myself). Just trying to work out how to make the keys optional now...

Answer (score 2):

Have solved this myself, posting an answer to help others: the correct syntax is:

```
type FXRatesBySymbol = {
  [Property in CurrencyPair]?: number;
};
```

The `?` makes the keys optional. The [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) does show this, but they only have an example using `keyof` so I had to adapt it to just use the type.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.